# only load @font-face being used in that page

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have multiple @font-face fonts in my stylesheet, is there a way of only load the ones being used on that page? Other than loading a separate stylesheet for each page that features that font.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know how browsers are really implementing it, but [CSS Fonts Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/) says in its "[Font loading guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-loading)" section, that browsers *must download only the fonts that are used in the current page*:

> The @font-face rule is designed to allow lazy loading of fonts, fonts are only downloaded when needed for use within a document. A stylesheet can include @font-face rules for a library of fonts of which only a select set are used; user agents must only download those fonts that are referred to within the style rules applicable to a given page. User agents that download all fonts defined in @font-face rules without considering whether those fonts are in fact used within a page are considered non-conformant.

So, anyway, in your code you can't specify any specific behavior, and if the browser is compliant, it will download only the ones required for each page.

Another consideration is if browsers will download fonts declared in the current page as a fallback but not really used. In this case, the specification says it is optional:

> In cases where a font might be downloaded in character fallback cases, user agents may download a font if it's listed in a font list but is not actually used for a given text run.

Comment: Thank you for this info. I will spend some time visiting in different browsers and checking the loading files again. Appreciate your help

Comment: I just tested this out today and here are my results: Firefox v26 and Chrome v32 both only download fonts if they are used in styling elements. You can have as many `@font-face` declarations as you want but they will only load the necessary ones. Internet Explorer v11 on the other hand, loads **ALL** fonts which are defined, regardless of whether they are actually used or not. Even the newest version of IE (as of writing this) is "non-conformant".

Answer (score -4):

You could just load the font within the page, that will override the font specified in the css.

for example:

```
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Krona+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Krona One', sans-serif;">
CONTENT
</body>
```

Comment: This is for an @font face not for google fonts, and was hoping I wouldnt have to load a separate style sheet. I was hoping there was a way of loading only the font defined in the CSS for that page