# font-face download all the fonts or just the used fonts?

Tags: css, font-face, font-family

i have a font-face folder in my public folder and a css that charge all font-face fonts

```
@font-face
    font-family font1
    src url('/fonts/font1-Regular.otf')
@font-face
    font-family font2
    src url('/fonts/font2-Regular.otf')
@font-face
    font-family font3
    src url('/fonts/font3-Regular.otf')
@font-face
    font-family font4
    src url('/fonts/font4-Regular.otf')
@font-face
    font-family font5
    src url('/fonts/font5-Regular.otf')
@font-face
    font-family font6
    src url('/fonts/font6-Regular.otf')
```

in my web the user can use any font that has in a list of fonts....

i want to know, all fonts are in the memory??? or just the used font... if i load more fonts ill be slowing down the speed charge of the web???

tnx all!

Comment: The code posted does not do anything, due to CSS syntax errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [only load @font-face being used in that page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690214/only-load-font-face-being-used-in-that-page)

Comment: there are no sintax errors, im using stylus thank you... i have the answer

Answer (score -3):

Requesting multiple fonts allows you to use all of those fonts in your page. (But don't go overboard; most pages don't need very many fonts, and requesting a lot of fonts may make your pages slow to load.)

Comment: The font-face rule is designed to allow lazy loading of fonts, fonts are only downloaded when needed for use within a document. A stylesheet can include font-face rules for a library of fonts of which only a select set are used; user agents must only download those fonts that are referred to within the style rules applicable to a given page. User agents that download all fonts defined in @font-face rules without considering whether those fonts are in fact used within a page are considered non-conformant.