# Does @font-face load all fonts to the browser

Tags: css, browser, browser-cache

I've been starting to use `@font-face` in the last year or so seeing that most major browsers support it now. I usually just use 1-3 fonts max, but most often I include the italics version, bold and italic bold version, which can easily amount to a couple MBs of data minimum (depending on the font). Since I use EOT, TTF, WOFF and SVG to work in most browsers, the filesize augments. I don't want too much bandwidth (and load time) used, so I was wondering: if Firefox (or any browser) successfully loads the EOT version of the file, will that browser still download all 3 others or it will specifically ignore the rest?

I know some of you might say "well, bandwidth nowadays...", but I still prefer to keep things minimal by habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the browsers will download the font even if its not used. Its very likely though that they are being cached once downloaded.

It might be best if you take off the ones that are not used for speed purposes!

Comment: Have you tested this? In Chrome (as noted in an answer below) only one  font file in the list is downloaded.

Comment: @Justin yes, time has gone by... at the time this question was made things were different than they're now!

Answer (score 10):

From my recent testing, the newest versions of the major browsers (FF v26, Chrome v32, & IE v11) all only download the font format file they need. Firefox and Chrome both seem to prefer `woff` files but also seem to work with `tff` or `otf` files, although `woff` fonts are smaller size so you should prefer those. IE seems to need `eot` fonts and the mobile browsers need `ttf` or `svg` (on older iOS) formats.

If you don't care about supporting mobile devices, you can get away with only used `eot` and `woff` files. Otherwise, you could do as [Tom van der Woerdt suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311218/346561) and use only `eot` and `ttf` which should work in FF, Chrome, Safari, IE, Droid, and iOS.

But since most browsers only load the file format they need, don't hesitate to include many formats. [Here is the most up-to-date recommendation for formats (and ordering)](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) you should use. Here are some tips for ["Preventing the Performance Hit from Custom Fonts"](http://css-tricks.com/preventing-the-performance-hit-from-custom-fonts/) which have helpful tricks like how to prevent loading fonts on mobile devices.

It is also worth mentioning that [the CSS3 spec says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9690795/346561) you *should* be able to have many `@font-face` declarations, even if they aren't used, and browsers should only download the fonts that are used. Firefox and Chrome follow this rule but IE is "non-conformant".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, browsers *may* choose to download all the fonts. But: you only need TTF and EOT to support all major browsers (IE8+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera). That should already help a lot.

Syntax for that (including hack so it works in IE) :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Futura Condensed";
    src: url('futura.eot?') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('futura.ttf') format('opentype');
}
```

Note the question mark after `.eot`, else it won't work in IE.

By reducing it to two fonts, you already save a lot on download size. If you want to reduce it even further, you could use things like per-browser stylesheets, or you could simply throw a 403 on one of the fonts when the user agent matches a browser that might load both.